# How to protect from CSAM flooding (similar to Swatting)

Tags: icloud

Apple recently introduced CSAM detection (https://www.apple.com/child-safety/), by which an iPhone device locally detects illegal photos, before uploading to iCloud, and reports any offender to law enforcement.

While this might be helpful in the intended way, I see a potential abuse:

An attacker might deliberately send offending pictures to a victim, with the intention that these get (automatically) uploaded to the victim's iCloud. Such a victim might then be targeted by law enforcement, similar to the well-known Swatting attack.

Apple does not talk about this in their post, so:

**How can an Apple user, with an iCloud account for legitimate use, mitigate such a CSAM flooding attack?**

Is there a way to "reject" such a crafted message in the first place, without even storing the offending image on the device? Would it make a difference when a "non-Apple" Messenger is receiving images, like WhatsApp or Instagram, instead of iMessage?

Comment: It would depend on the backup schedule of the app, I guess? WhatsApp backs up to iCloud once a day. Instagram does not backup to iCloud, to my knowledge. You can deactivate automatic image download on WhatsApp, and both WhatsApp and Instagram will put unknown senders on a "holding" area so you can decide wether to allow or block their messages. Also, such attacker will need access to CSAM and risk attracting attention to themselves. I use iMessage sparsely, I'd have to familiarize with its handling of unknown senders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no attack to mitigate really as the premise behind the attack is flawed.

Apple's new CSAM detection will work in iCloud Photos - not in iCloud Messages. Someone sending you CSAM as a swatting attack will not trigger the CSAM detection. It doesn't matter if it is sent by Apple Messages, Facebook Messenger, WhatsApp or Instagram.

If you, the user, decides that you want to keep the CSAM you have been attacked with and start saving it to iCloud Photos - instead of reporting it to the authorities - then you have a problem. However the problem is probably not the CSAM detection, but rather something worse.

Comment: You are right, Apple talks about iCloud Photos, specifically. So, as long as no messaging app can/is configured to save photos to iCloud Photos, the user stays safe from such an attack.